# Refactor method access modifier in visual studio (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have the following problem. I'm working in visual studio. Let's say, I have an abstract method in base class.

```
public abstract void DoSomething();
```

And I override this method in derived classes.

```
public override void DoSomething();
```

How can I change the access modifier in base and derived classes automatically? I've tried to use Resharper, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: How many do you need to change?

Comment: I need to change about 70 files.

Comment: I can't see a way to do this other than regex

Answer (score 1):

With ReSharper:

1. Place caret to "public" keyword in the method signature
2. Press "Alt+Enter" and select new desired modifier (ie "to protected")
   Result: modifiers for all methods in the hierarchy are changed